# Optional arguments and InteropServices

Tags: c#, optional-arguments

I'm using for the firs time optional arguments but I cannot understand difference between those two method definitions:

```
private void method1([Optional, DefaultParameterValue(string.Empty)] string testString)
{
    //do something
}

private void method2(string testString = "")
{
    //do something
}
```

definition of method1 needs:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

Method2 definition is smaller and needs no import.

Have I to consider something before using one of those method syntax?

Comment: Method 2 is new in C# 4. Method 1 has been there since .NET 1.1.

Comment: @Etienne de Martel that should be an answer.

Comment: @vcsjones I felt like it was too short to be a proper answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method 1 was present since .NET 1.1.

Method 2 was introduced with C# 4 (C# did not support optional parameters until then).